# PHP Script to Edit Database Fields

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a working registration component purchased for Joomla that stores the users information in a database. I have a few hidden fields that need to match up exactly with the inputs of other fields, however the component does not allow fields to change dynamically on registration.

I'd like to use a cron job to select the relevant field from the database and set that value as the hidden field value, for every user.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get started on this PHP script?

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing that `cron` is for.

Comment: I figured it was a cron task. Just looking for more direction on the PHP end

Comment: You'll have to edit your question, in that case. There's nothing too tricky with running PHP from the command line. Alternatively, if you've got users updating information and that needs updating across different tables, you could also do those updates when the user submits them, rather than as a cron job.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have edited my question to be more PHP specific.

Comment: You might want to tag it as Joomla, too - it's possible there's functionality built in to do what you want. Otherwise, you just need to write a script to make a connection to the database and run the queries, just as if it was being called from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

cron

`man cron`

Introduction to cron: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

From this intro:

> In the /etc directory you will probably find some sub directories called 'cron.hourly', 'cron.daily', 'cron.weekly' and 'cron.monthly'. If you place a script into one of those directories it will be run either hourly, daily, weekly or monthly, depending on the name of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON, it's is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like ( ex. Linux ) operating systems. This the simplest solution

Here are some tutorials:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Hope this helps